# how to find dynamically created CheckBox checked in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I created Check Box dynamically inside a wrap panel in wpf. How to find the checked check box in code behind.

Comment: Can you please add relevant code?

Comment: As long as you name the checkbox, you should be able to find it easily

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a more compact not reusable and specialized version..

```
WrapPanel wp = new WrapPanel();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    CheckBox chb = new CheckBox();
    chb.Name = string.Format("Id{0}", i);
    wp.Children.Add(chb);
}

foreach (CheckBox el in wp.Children)
{
    if (el.Name == "Id3")
    {
        return el;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/// <summary>
/// Finds a Child of a given item in the visual tree. 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parent">A direct parent of the queried item.</param>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the queried item.</typeparam>
/// <param name="childName">x:Name or Name of child. </param>
/// <returns>The first parent item that matches the submitted type parameter. 
/// If not matching item can be found, 
/// a null parent is being returned.</returns>
public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
    where T : DependencyObject
{
    // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
    if (parent == null) return null;

    T foundChild = null;

    int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
    for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
    {
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
        // If the child is not of the request child type child
        T childType = child as T;
        if (childType == null)
        {
            // recursively drill down the tree
            foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

            // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
            if (foundChild != null) break;
        }
        else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
        {
            var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
            // If the child's name is set for search
            if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
            {
                // if the child's name is of the request name
                foundChild = (T)child;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // child element found.
            foundChild = (T)child;
            break;
        }
    }

    return foundChild;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for the text of the selected checkbox do somthing like thes:

```
         private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       string a =checkBox1.Text;
    }
```